# How to force the next node to visit in VRPTWs without changing time window

Tags: or-tools

Let's say I have 3 pairs of pickup and delivery(6 nodes), and their own time windows.

```
0-Node_start #Index(0)
1-Pickup, 2-Delivery #Index(1,2)
3-Pickup, 4-Delivery #Index(3,4)
5-Pickup, 6-Delivery #Index(5,6)
7-Node_end #Index(7)
```

How can I force my vehicle to go from node start to index_3, then continue with the rest of the route directly without changing the time window of a node in index_3, or changing the traveling time to 0 from node_0 to node_3? This should be possible regardless of the time taken from index_0 to index_3, as long as time windows allow.

Also, not sure if this is important in this case, but I use FirstSolutionStrategy.GLOBAL_CHEAPEST_ARC

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for my case, hopeful it will work for others too. I used [NextVar](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/constraint_solver/pywrapcp?hl=en#nextvar)

```
consecutive_locations = [[1,3], [7,9]]
for location_index in consecutive_locations:
    routing.solver().Add(routing.NextVar(location_index[0]) == location_index[1])
```

I used a loop because I have multiple vehicles, each vehicle has a specific starting point, and a location I want it to visit next after starting point.

The solution takes longer though, I think firstSolutionStrategy might be the issue(Not sure)